# Discord.py exception "Missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx' " although I included 'ctx' as one of the function parameters

Tags: discord, discord.py

so I'm having an issue while creating a discord music bot and I've been trying to solve it for a while now, but I can't find any solution.

Here's the constructor and three functions to search and play music that are necessary for the command to actually work (I'll only include the skip command since I get the same exception with the rest of the commands)

```
class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {"format": "bestaudio", "noplaylist": "True"}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5", "options": "-vn"}

        self.vc = None

        
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]["source"]

            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc == await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("I'm sorry, but I can't join the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
            
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())

        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    
    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]["source"]

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False


    def search(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:{0}".format(item), download=False)["entries"][0]
            except Exception:
                return False
        return {"source": info["formats"][0]["url"], "title": info["title"]}

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(music(client))
```

bot.py with setup_hook and the command

```
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.load_extension("dustobot")

@commands.command(aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song that is being played")
    async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx) #Calling a function that plays the next song in a queue
```

And this is the error I get:

```
2023-01-21 12:28:37 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command skip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\private_path\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: music.skip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\private_path\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke 
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\private_path\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\private_path\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped       
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: music.skip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Is it because I'm using a deprecated discord.py syntax?

Thanks in advance for taking your time to help me, I really appreciate it.

Btw this is my main.py:

```
import os
import discord
from dustobot import music #This imports the music class
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

client.remove_command("help") #I have my own help command


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the way you created the command:

```py
    #client refers to the bot
    @client.command(aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song that is being played")
```

The decorator doesn't expect this to be a method in a class. As such, it's not *invoked* as a method either, so `self` won't be passed automatically and the `Context` will be the first argument (`self`). As a result, the library won't pass a value for `ctx`, which results in your error.

In cogs, commands should be created using `@commands.command` instead of `@<Bot_instance>.command`, the reason being that you shouldn't have your `Bot` instance *available* to you in that scope.

You could've also gotten this by reading the [manual for Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#cogs)...

> Every command is marked with the `commands.command()` decorator.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for the clarification. Know I'm getting a "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "skip" is not found" error. I first tried including in the command  the parameters (name="skip", aliases=["s"]) and then without including the "name" parameter, but keeps giving me the same error. Thanks for your patience,  I'm a rookie after all :(

Comment: Are you loading the cog?

Comment: I think so. I'm editing the question to include the main.py in case you see any mistake

Comment: Where are you calling that `load_cog` function?

Comment: Actually, now that I realize, I didn't call the function. Do you know where I should call it? If I write load_cog() just below the function, I get this error "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'load_cog' was never awaited
  load_cog()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Comment: Yes, because it's async so you have to `await` it, which you can only do inside of another async function.. The docs explain how to do it properly: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Comment: I don't think I did it properly, cause I'm getting a "discord.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'dustobot' has no 'setup' function." error (I edited the question again)

Comment: Read the error, your Cog file doesn't have a `setup` method, **you added it in the main file instead of the extension's file**. The link I sent above also tells you how to do that. Also, you're loading it twice. The link gives you two different methods ("after, using setup_hook" and "after, using async_with"). You added **both**... I recommend using the `setup_hook` one because `client.start()` doesn't configure logging for you.

Comment: I edited the main.py and also added the setup_hook on the music extension class, but keeps giving me the command not found exception (updated the question)

Comment: By the way it's okay if you get tired and decide to stop helping me, I totally understand that I'm taking too much of your time.

Comment: You added the `setup_hook` function to your cog and the `setup()` function to the main file. `setup_hook` is a method of `Client` so you're supposed to just override the method in a subclass, like the first example showed you ("after, using setup_hook"). The`setup()` function is supposed to be in the extension file, not your main.

Comment: Edited the question again (I'm getting the same error again)

Comment: `setup_hook` is _still_ in your `Cog`, I said you're supposed to override it in your `Bot` subclass like the example in the link shows & that it _doesn't_ belong in the Cog/extension file. The `skip` command is also _outside_ of your cog instead of inside of it, and you're _still_ using `@client.command` instead of `@commands.command` like my original answer said.....

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about not updating the @commands.command in the question, I changed that some time ago. The setup() function is supposed to go in bot.py as well? Bot.py is a new file that I created to include commands and the setup_hook()

Comment: No, like I said a before the `setup` function goes in the **extension**'s file (the one where your cog is), it has nothing to do with your main or `Bot` or whatever. If you look in this comment section I've said that part like 3-4 times now.

Comment: Yeah you're right, you already said it several times and I got it updated. The bot keeps not taking any commands (my code is exactly what's shown in the updated question).

Comment: Now you're still making 2 mistakes. 1: the `skip` command is inside of your `Bot` instead of being inside of your `Cog`. 2: in your main your `client` variable is an instance of `commands.Bot` instead of your own custom subclass. You've now created the class correctly, but you're not using it. You're still running a regular `Bot` which has no idea that it should load extensions.

Comment: OMG I CAN'T BELIEVE IT, the bot takes the commands. I can't hear any song but I think that's because of wrongly using the ffmpeg or youtube_dl incorrectly, but I can solve that. THANK YOU SO MUCH you're a legend

Comment: Hi, I know its been a while but I've been trying to get this to work in so many ways. I tried your code with the recommendations here but Its still not recognising the command.

By any chance please could you explain a bit more how you got it to work, would be great. Thanks

Comment: @Tester321 I'd recommend making a new post with your code fragment so people can help you more easily. The comment section here spiraled a bit out of control. If you show what you tried, we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Oh thanks for replying, I'll make my own post but more specifically I've been trying to understand what you meant by " in your main your client variable is an instance of commands.Bot instead of your own custom subclass. You've now created the class correctly, but you're not using it. You're still running a regular Bot which has no idea that it should load extensions. "

I tried client = music but that doesn't work.

Thanks either way.

Comment: @Tester321 OP created a subclass, but wasn't using it. Their `Bot` variable was created using `commands.Bot`, which is not their subclass but the base class from the library. As a result, it didn't do anything, nor have any of the functionality that they implemented in their subclass.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. My IDE did highlight that line saying that "Redeclarded 'bot' defined above without usage"
How would you initialise it though, because I believe that is my problem as well. I am using the same code as the op except with a few more commands.
I moved the command like you said into the music file and added a setup but still it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It's just a class, you initialize it the same way you initialize any other class. What problems are you running into with initializing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252823/discussion-between-tester321-and-stijndcl).